# Undecidable definition of mathematical expressions?

Tags: definitions, decidability

I am arguing a bit on Facebook regarding the definition of a mathematical expression. Some argue that equations are not expressions (and there are a few possibly dubious online sources which states this).
Let's say that equations are *not* expressions, but both sides of an equation are considered expressions.
Now,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |\{x \in \mathbb{C} : x^k-1=0\}|
$$
is still an expression, but it contains equations. So, by not allowing equations in the set of expressions, we run into the issue that parts of an expression may not be expressions anymore.

The question I have is: *Is it a decidable problem if a finite string of math symbols is **an expression** or not?*

As this is really about the definition of what an expression *is*, the above (in my opinion wrong) "definition" makes the question more interesting, I think.

To reword, is there a definition of the term *mathematical expression* which sounds reasonable, but is troublesome in the sense that it is in general undecidable if a finite string IS an expression?

Comment: The notion that equations aren't expressions probably comes from programming. In most C-like languages an *expression* is something that evaluates to a value at runtime, like `a + 2`, while an assignment like `b = a + 2;` is a *statement*. Many people associate assignments with equations, probably because of the symbol `=`. Somewhat confusingly, the equality test `b == a + 2` is an expression since it evaluates to a Boolean value...

Comment: True, byt high level languaged such as mathematica allow for assigning equations to variables. This is quite convenient

Comment: Part "/2" of an expression "1/2", is very often not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, this is really a question of the definition of "expression". It sounds to me like you're taking it to mean "constant term". If so, given any reasonable mathematical language it will be decidable whether a given finite string is a constant term.

The concern that "parts of an expression may not be expressions any more" puzzles me --- why would you expect this?

I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to cook up a language in which you could write things like "$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ where $a_n = 0$ or $1$ depending on whether the $n$th Turing machine halts on null input" or whatever, and declare that things like this only count as constant terms if they converge. That could make termhood undecidable.